# Call OrigCountryRegionId from InventTable

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to retrieve the value of field `ShortName` from the table `LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation` based on the `OrigCountryRegionId` and the `LanguageID` fields, the `LanguageId` is retrieved from the `CustPackingSlipJour`.

I am having troubles to retrieve the `OrigCountryRegionId` from the `InventTable`.

The method `InventTable` exists on the table `CustPackingSlipTrans`, so i want to retrieve the value of the field `OrigCountryRegionId` on the `ItemId`, which is returned on the `InventTable` method on the `CustPackingSlipTrans` table.

I have a piece of code, but not sure how to implement the solution as described above.

```
salesPackingSlipTmp.OrigCountryRegionName = LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation::find(CustPackingSlipTrans*I am lost here*, CustPackingSlipJour.LanguageId, false).ShortName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inventTable` method returns an InventTable buffer so you can just retrieve the fields like this:

```
CustPackingSlipTrans.inventTable().fieldName
```

So your code would look like:

```
salesPackingSlipTmp.OrigCountryRegionName = LogisticsAddressCountryRegionTranslation::find(CustPackingSlipTrans.inventTable().OrigCountryRegionId, CustPackingSlipJour.LanguageId, false).ShortName;
```